# How to implement INSTREAM protocal for clamd in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sockets, daemon

I am struggling to implement the INSTREAM command of clamd daemon in Ruby.
Here is the document of [clamd](http://www.clamav.net/doc/latest/html/node28.html)

```
@file = File.open("input.txt")
socket = TCPSocket.new(HOST, PORT)
#writing the command
socket.write("zINSTREAM\0")
#streaming the chunk
socket.write(1024) #size of chunk
socket.write(@file.read(1024)) #chunk of data
#end the streaming
socket.write(0)
puts "Reading from the scoket"
puts socket.recv(1024)
socket.close
```

But I am always receiving the error response "INSTREAM size limit exceeded. ERROR"
What I doing wrong here?

Comment: From the documentation link you provided: "Streaming is terminated by sending a zero-length chunk. Note: do not exceed StreamMaxLength as defined in clamd.conf, otherwise clamd will reply with INSTREAM size limit exceeded and close the connection." What ist your clamd.conf?

Comment: I have checked the clamd.conf. StreamMaxLength 25M . The content of input.txt is not greater that 25 megabytes.

Comment: Are you sure have to send a null termination right after the `zINSTREAM`command? Shouldn't it just be `socket.write("zINSTREAM")`?

Comment: refer this in code socket.write("zINSTREAM\0")

Answer (score 3):

After the long struggle I found the solution for this.

The size of the chunk must be expressed in 4 byte unsigned integer in [network byte order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571715/how-to-convert-32-bit-integer-to-network-byte-order/12571746#12571746)

So

```
socket.write(1024)
```

should be

```
socket.write([1024].pack("N"))
```