# How to convert 32 bit integer to network byte order?

Tags: ruby, endianness

How to convert the 32 bit integer to network byte order.

What is the right way to do that?

```
[1024].pack("N")
```

OR

```
[1,0,2,4].pack("N")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, look at the output of each:

```
>> [1024].pack("N")
=> "\000\000\004\000"
>> [1,0,2,4].pack("N")
=> "\000\000\000\001"
```

Note what the second is missing:

```
>> [1,0,2,4].pack("NNNN")
=> "\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\002\000\000\000\004"
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. I don't know how to thank you.
1000.times { puts "Thank you" }

Comment: But my irb gives the following result for the same code.
"\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x04"

Does \x and \0 means the same?

Comment: `"\x00"` is the same thing as `"\0"`, just represented in different bases.  See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Backslash_Notation