# Ruby how to convert 32 bit integer to network byte order?

Tags: ruby, sockets, endianness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert 32 bit integer to network byte order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571715/how-to-convert-32-bit-integer-to-network-byte-order)

I already asked "[How to convert 32 bit integer to network byte order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571715/how-to-convert-32-bit-integer-to-network-byte-order)" but still I don't understand the concept.

I need to write the length of the data to socket in network byte order.

For example if the size of the data in bytes is 1024 then I need to express this as network byte order in Ruby.

As per the answer for my earlier question it will be:

```
[1,0,2,4].pack("NNNN")
```

But when I try this it also works:

```
[10,24].pack("NN")
[4,2,0,1].pack("NNNN")
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: They produce different results - pick the one which provides the outgput you want (I would have thought that was [1024].pack('N'))

Comment: I am not sure which one is correct actually. When I use [1024].pack("N") this results stream length exceed error. Actually maximum stream length is set to 25M. So I am totally confused.

Comment: If you asked it before, you shouldn't ask it again. By modifying your previous question to make it more clear, you'd cause it to become active and more people would see it again.

Answer (score 4):

Correct way to convert 32 bit integer to network byte order in Ruby is

```
#[integer].pack("N")
[1024].pack("N")
```