# ntohl() and htonl() in Ruby?

Tags: c, ruby, sockets, endianness, htonl

I am doing some low level bit manipulation in Ruby and was wondering if there was the Ruby equivalent of the `htonl()` and `ntohl()` functions in C?

I came across the .pack method, but does `[1024].pack("N")` provide a suitable replacement for htonl?

Comment: This should help: https://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/4-what-the-pack.html

Comment: I think this question has been asked already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706052/ruby-how-to-convert-32-bit-integer-to-network-byte-order . Hope that helps.